# HTML5 Font Tag Alternative in Label

Tags: html, tags

I have a label tag and I want to change part of the texts font in that label. Before I use to use font tag but now its being dropped completely in html5 and I am not so sure how I can do it. The only way I know is have a nested label.

Old way 
`<label>some text <font> Fonted TEXT</font><label>`

new way?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to add semantic meaning use a `<span>` tag instead:

```
<label>some text <span>Fonted TEXT</span></label>
```

And style it with CSS like this:

```
label > span {}
```

If you want to emphasize the text you can also use `<em>` or `<strong>`. You can read about those tags on HTML5 Doctor: "[The i, b, em, & strong elements](http://html5doctor.com/i-b-em-strong-element/)"